# Command links no longer work after submitting the form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

i have implemented a search function in a datatable using primefaces, it is a simple search that just searches all fields for the value the user has entered, this is working just fine, however when i search the required field, i get the results fine but now my commandlinks do not work, they work fine before i search but once the search results are displayed the commandlinks no longer work, how can i make these work on a search ?

here is the datatable

```
<p:dataTable id="UserTable"
              widgetVar="usersTable" 
              value="#{userdetailsController.items}"
              var="item"
              emptyMessage="No details was found with given criteria">
   <!--filteredValue="{userdetailsController.filteredUsers}" -->

   <f:facet name="header">  
      <p:outputPanel>  
         <h:outputText value="Search all fields: " />  
         <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="usersTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
      </p:outputPanel>  
   </f:facet>

   <p:column id="USERID" filterBy="id"   
              headerText="i.d."  
              filterMatchMode="contains">
      <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsTitle_id}"/>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
    </p:column>

    <!--There are four different match modes, "startsWith"(default), "endsWith", "contains" and "exact"-->
    <p:column id="USERNAME" filterBy="username"   
               headerText="username."   
               filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">
           <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsTitle_username}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.username}"/>
     </p:column>

     <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
           <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:commandLink action="#{userdetailsController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsViewLink}"/>
        <h:outputText value=" "/>
        <div class="divider"/>

        <p:commandLink action="#{userdetailsController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsEditLink}"/>
        <h:outputText value=" "/>
        <div class="divider"/>

        <p:commandLink actionListener="#{userdetailsController.destroy}" value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsDestroyLink}" 
                       ajax="true" update="UserTable"/>
     </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of possible remedies you can try.

First add a filteredValue to your dataTable: `filteredValue="#{userdetailsController.filteredItems}"`

You'll need to add the supporting List to your userdetailsController.

Also, for your column filters change the field reference to use EL: `filterBy="#{item.username}"`

Depending on your version of PrimeFaces, your globalFilter inputText may need to reference the dataTable like this: `onkeyup="PF('usersTable').filter()"` to get the global filter working properly.

One other issue I ran into, my WildFly app server didn't like the inclusion of `"&nbsp;"`. It wouldn't even load the page, so you might want to consider using an alternative if this causes your app server a problem.

Here's the entire solution with a different named backing bean and no resource bundle:

```
<h:form id="exampleForm2" prependId="false">

    <p:dataTable id="UserTable"
                     widgetVar="usersTable"
                     value="#{collectorView.items}"
                     filteredValue="#{collectorView.filteredItems}"
                     var="item"

                     emptyMessage="No details was found with given criteria">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields: " />
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('usersTable').filter()" style="width:150px" />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>

            <p:column id="USERID" filterBy="#{item.id}"
                      headerText="i.d."
                      filterMatchMode="contains">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <!--There are four different match modes, "startsWith"(default), "endsWith", "contains" and "exact"-->
            <p:column id="USERNAME" filterBy="#{item.username}"
                      headerText="username."
                      filterMatchMode="contains">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.username}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value=" "/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandLink action="#{collectorView.prepareView}" value="View"/>
                <h:outputText value=" "/>
                <div class="divider"/>
                <p:commandLink action="#{collectorView.prepareEdit}" value="Edit"/>
                <h:outputText value=" "/>
                <div class="divider"/>
                <p:commandLink action="#{collectorView.destroy}" value="Delete"
                               update="UserTable" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
```

If none of these remedies solve your problem, then the issue is likely elsewhere. Failed javascript as the other answer suggests will also cause the symptoms you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the javascript console is displaying any errors or warning? it's a common issue when using primeface plus, you can tell us if you're using multiple forms which might as well lead to a malfuction of commandlink.

so far the code you provide can't give enough clues... IMO